xscreensaver: How to unlock after locking?
I'd like my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5 with Debian Bookworm (updated, vanilla) automatically lock after e.g. 5 minutes without user interaction. Unlocking should require user credentials, similar to what I am used to on Windows machines, and NOT terminate running processes.
From google search I figured xscreensaver should be the most straight forward option.

However when using Lock Screen after or File -> Lock Screen now, I am not able to unlock. I just see the screensaver with no option to enter any user credentials. The only way to to proceed from here is Ctrl + Alt + F1 -> login -> sudo reboot. If only blanking the screen, mouse wiggling brings me back to desktop, as expected.
What do I need to do to unlock the machine after Locking by xscreensaver?
As a variant i tried light-locker, but failed:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install light-locker
light-locker-settings
>>bash: light-locker-settigs: command not found

